# Android File.createTempFile throwing IOException

Tags: android, kotlin, file

Been banging my head on this for a while now (~16hrs). Looked up SO posts scoured all over the internet. Tried replacing with createNewFile() api as well, didn't work either. For the life of it not sure whats causing this.Help appreciated. Code snippet below,

```kotlin
fun createImgFile(context: Context): File? {
    return try {
        val fileTimeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(Date())
        val fileName = "MyImg_$fileTimeStamp"
        File.createTempFile(fileName, null, context.cacheDir)
    } catch (exception: IOException) {
        exception.printStackTrace()
        null
    }
}
```

The context being passed is the LocalContext.current from a Composable function. Running on a Pixel3a emulator running Android API 33.

replaced createTempFile() with file.createNewFile(). The one thing I noticed is that when simply creating a file reference (i.e just in memory and nothing created on disk), things work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IO Exception in your case is because of your provided path.
because the name which you provided is contain slash that means you are creating a file inside a directory which is not exist, So to solve this problem you can simply change the format of Date to another exclude slash character.

try this:

```kotlin
 val fileTimeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(Date())
 val fileName = "MyImg_$fileTimeStamp"
```

Comment: Thank you!  Now that's a great eye. Sincerely appreciated.